# Почему не открываются нужные окна?

Tags: javascript

```js
var t;
t=prompt("Сколько лет?");
document.write("Мне ", t, " лет");

if (confirm("Закрыть вкладку?"))
    window.close();

function a();
{
    alert("Привет!");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Кнопки </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<script src="JS\alert.js" ></script>
<script src="JS\prompt.js" ></script>
<script src="JS\confirm.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><input type="button" value=" alert " onclick="a()"></p>
<p><input type="button" value=" prompt " onclick="b()"></p>
<p><input type="button" value=" confirm " onclick="c()"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`Гляньте на код и скажите почему нет вкладки привет и почему оно пишет тебе сколько лет а не сколько лет и почему пишет закрыть активную вкладку а не просто закрыть вкладку.

Comment: Вы бы запятые в тексте вопроса расставили. Потому что либо код работает совсем не так, как указано в вопросе, либо вы хотели спросить что-то другое.

Comment: зачем вы добавили `;` после объявления функции?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btnAlert = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-alert');
const btnPrompt = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-prompt');
const btnConfirm = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-confirm');

function alertFunc() {
  alert('Привет!');
}

function confirmFunc() {
  const confirmResult = confirm('Вы хотите закрыть вкладку?');
  if (confirmResult === true) {
    window.close();
  } else {
    console.log('Не закрыть');
  }
}

function promptFunc() {
  const age = prompt("Сколько лет?");
  
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('prompt');
  div.innerHTML = `Вам ${age} лет`;
  document.body.append(div);
  
}

btnAlert.addEventListener('click', alertFunc);
btnConfirm.addEventListener('click', confirmFunc);
btnPrompt.addEventListener('click', promptFunc);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #2bbbad;
}

.prompt {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-alert">Alert</div>
<div class="btn btn-prompt">Prompt</div>
<div class="btn btn-confirm">Confirm</div>
<br>
```